# AWS CloudWatch RUM integration in React Package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I was trying to track client side logs & errors and my web service is deployed in ec2 machine AWS in ap-south-1(Mumbai)region.

AWS CloudWatch RUM is one option for the logs-dashboard thing but while implementing i got to know that it is not available in ap-south-1(Mumbai)region.

Is their any way through which i can integrate RUM in ap-south-1(Mumbai)region?

Is there any other option that i can explore in AWS for the client side logging and dashboard.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Added the script in my webservice package

`<script>(function(n,i,v,r,s,c,x,z){x=window.AwsRumClient={q:[],n:n,i:i,v:v,r:r,c:c};window[n]=function(c,p){x.q.push({c:c,p:p});};z=document.createElement('script');z.async=true;z.src=s;document.head.insertBefore(z,document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]);}).....` 
but while creating the monitor in AWS cloudwatch, the RUM is not available in ap-south-1(Mumbai)region.